# Call function asynchronously from within flask app that runs continuously

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, celery

I have a Flask app that integrates with Dropbox.  I need to create one instance of a `DropboxClient` per user by calling `fetch_dropbox_data()`.

I can't seem to identify how I should call `fetch_dropbox_data()` such that it:

1. Doesn't block the user's interaction with the web app
2. Only runs in one instance per user
3. Can be started/restarted with or without user interaction

Should I use something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this?  Or is there some other approach that would work better?  I started down the path of using `multiprocessing`, but it doesn't seem to fit the requirements.  I would certainly appreciate any pointers.  Thanks!

Here's a minimal example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/some/route/')
def route():

    session_access_token = "some_access_token"

    # Need to call this asynchronously as to not block
    fetch_dropbox_data(session_access_token)

    return "ok"

# Only one DropboxClient instance should be created per user
def fetch_dropbox_data(session_access_token):


    client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(session_access_token)

    cursor = None
    while True:
        result = client.delta(cursor)
        cursor = result['cursor']
        if result['reset']:
            print 'RESET'

        for dir_path, metadata in result['entries']:
            print "in the for loop"
            if metadata is not None:
                print '%s was created/updated by' % (dir_path)

            else:
                print '%s was deleted by %s' % (dir_path, session_access_token)

        # if has_more is true, call delta again immediately
        if not result['has_more']:

            changes = False
            # poll until there are changes
            while not changes:
                response = requests.get('https://api-notify.dropbox.com/1/longpoll_delta',
                    params={
                        'cursor': cursor,  # latest cursor from delta call
                        'timeout': 120     # default is 30 seconds
                    })
                data = response.json()

                print "data: %s" % data

                changes = data['changes']
                if not changes:
                    print 'Timeout, polling again...'

                backoff = data.get('backoff', None)
                if backoff is not None:
                    print 'Backoff requested. Sleeping for %d seconds...' % backoff
                    time.sleep(backoff)
                print 'Resuming polling...'

    return 'Authenticated.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could continue down the path of using multiprocessing to perform your async function calls as you can see in the VERY basic example below.

```
import multiprocessing

class MetaSingleton(type):
    instance = None
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(MetaSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance

class PoolManager(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaSingleton


    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = None

    def create_pool(self, count=4):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=count)

    def use_worker(self, func, params, tout=1): 
        result = self.pool.apply_async(func, params)    
        return result.get(timeout=tout)           

    def map_workers(self, func, params):
        return self.pool.map(func, params)

    def get_pool(self):
        return self.pool       

if __name__ == '__main__':


    def test1(x):
        return x*x


    a = PoolManager()
    print id(a)
    a.create_pool()
    print a.get_pool()

    print a.use_worker(test1, [10])



    b = PoolManager()
    print id(b)
    print b.get_pool()

    print b.use_worker(test1, [10])
```

This would need to be extended to track users execution.